# Detect inside webpack file which package.json script command was run

Tags: webpack, package.json

In webpack.config.js file, I need the publicPath to be `http://localhost:3000` when I use it in development (`npm run dev`) and for production (`npm run build`) I need it to be `/dist`.

Currently, when I want production build I always manually change the publicPath from `http://localhost:3000` to `/dist`. Is there a way that I can do that automatically based on the npm script command being run? it shall automatically use `http://localhost:3000` when `npm run dev` and `/dist` when `npm run build`.

package.json-file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
},
```

webpack-file:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000'
    publicPath: '/dist'
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `webpack.config.js` module exports into a function and access `mode` via `argv`:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        ...
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'dist' : 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    }
};
```